# How to make a background image bootstrap responsive when not full screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a design that I'm converting to be Bootstrap responsive but have run into a couple of problems.

1. How to make a non full width background image responsive
2. How to keep the main form content the correct distance away from the top of the image no matter what the viewport size.

Mock up **[image](http://www.handcoded.co.uk/stack/mockup.jpg)**

**[Website](http://www.handcoded.co.uk/stack/)**

I'd be very grateful for any pointers

Comment: cant you just use the `background-size` property, and use percentages ? Or use a site container grid of 4 x 4 x 4 and the centre 4 will contain background image (and content)?

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: Do you want to fill the blank space around the image ? But with what ?

Comment: Not concerned about the blank spacing around the background so long as the background image resizes down and I have a way to easily position the form so that it is always the correct the distance from the top of the background.

Answer (score 2):

The following is one simple option, according to your mockup-Website.

1. Create a parent DIV that is center aligned on the page.
2. Apply a background image to this DIV and set its max-width to 100%.
3. Create another div that will sit on top of the parent DIV (and is relative to the parent DIV).
4. Give its top margin the required %.
5. It is recommended that you create these styles on media queries for responsive display.

There are a lot of StackOverflow topics the will help you through with the above steps.

HTH.

Comment: A jsfiddle would really help me to understand this better but I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

To fix problem 1: on the body you can use: background-size:contain;

Comment: Tried that but the image does not resize at smaller screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

First, for the background image:

```
div.someclass{ 
 background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

This will make your background image responsive, i.e. it will fit according to the size of the display the page is viewed on.

Second, to keep the main form content a proper margin from above on any device is to give the div you just created for the main content a relative margin on top:

```
div.someclass{
margin-top:5%;
}
```

change the above *5%* according to your requirement.